How to use osmnx on air gapped computers
Ansys has some examples using pyaedt like SBR_City_Import.py.
It uses SRTM and OSMNX which rely on visiting some url's. I am trying to find how to run it on a machine without internet. We can transfer some files securely to these machines, but can't do https requests (any request that requires going out of the network). Have figured out srtm part, but need suggestion for osmnx. I believe this is not the first request to use osmnx offline and someone already knows how. Appreciate any help.
Tried to track down the lines where connection was being made to the server.

Please present you problem in actual code, including your observed and desired outcome.

If you want to use OSMnx offline, you could download the map on a computer connected to the internet with ox.save_graphml(), and load the graph with ox.load_graphml().
To do this, it looks like you'd need to patch this line in PyAEDT, to first find out the lat/lon point and radius it wants to query, and then later substitute the GeoDataFrame loaded by ox.load_graphml().
Have not tried this, so YMMV.
